# PFQueryTableViewController with custom cell crashes on launch

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a PFQueryTableViewController subclass (DebateQueryViewController) that I want to use a custom cell with. The DebateQueryViewController is in a storyboard, and I have the .xib for my custom cell. I have also created .h and .m files for the cell, but I have not changed the code in them, except for adding the outlets for the labels, etc in the xib file.

In the viewDidLoad method of DebateQueryViewController.m file I have this:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"RipDebateTableCell"
                                               bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
         forCellReuseIdentifier:@"debateCell"];
```

I also have these two methods:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 73;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"debateCell";

    RipDebateTableCell *cell = (RipDebateTableCell * )[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //[df setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy "];
    NSString *my = [df stringFromDate:[object objectForKey:@"Date"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", my);
    tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

    cell.titleOf.text = [object objectForKey:@"Topic"];
    cell.dateOf.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@", my];
    cell.typeOf.text = @"Debate";
    cell.cellTop.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table-top"];
    //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    //cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```

Everything was working perfectly until I tried implementing custom cells, but now the app crashes on the launch image every single time.

Comment: Give details of the exception, message and stack trace.

Comment: All that logs is (lldb), and @autoreleasepool { is highlighted in green with Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1 next to it.